# ¿En qué consiste un apuntador tipo void (en lenguaje C)?

Tags: c

Necesito saber para que sirve por que estoy haciendo unos ejercicios en C y no se para que sirve el apuntador de tipo void; en uno me pide usarlo pero no se para que sirve y en google hay información pero no es muy entendible.

Comment: Hola Fernando.. has probado buscarlo en google? hay algo que no entiendas en particular sobre el?

Comment: Hola, si, lo eh buscado pero me gustaría escuchar que es para un programador o alguien que ya lo haya utilizado.

Comment: y que has encontrado al respecto? la respuesta a esto es seguramente lo mismo que has encontrado. Void es nada.

Comment: Este es un tema hermoso, un puntero void (`void *`) es una de las cosas mas potentes en **C**, voto por que se abra nuevamente la pregunta o por lo menos abrir una discucion sobre el, ya que google no encotraran mucha informacion de el.

Comment: @Shassain eres libre de hacer la pregunta en meta.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/fxky5d0w.aspx

Comment: @gbianchi Es nada o todo, un puntero a void en C es el equivalente a devolver Object en Java o C#, puedes (sin casting) asignarlo a cualquier tipo de puntero. Más info que se podría añadir en la respuesta: http://www.zator.com/Cpp/E4_2_1d.htm