# ¿Qué es la palabra reservada 'void' en los distintos lenguajes que la utilizan?

Tags: c++, c

He leído por ahí una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104188/en-qu%C3%A9-consiste-un-apuntador-tipo-void-en-lenguaje-c) que trataba sobre el puntero a `void` o `void *` y me ha surgido la duda sobre la palabra reservada `void` de varios lenguajes.

Tengo este código:

```
typedef enum VALUE_TYPE {
  VT_INTEGER, VT_STRING, VT_BOOL, VT_NULL
} valuetype_t;

typedef struct VALUE {
  void *iv;
  valuetype_t tp;
} value_t;
```

Pero no entiendo mucho para que sirve el `void *` en el `struct`.

Según tengo entendido, en [c](/questions/tagged/c) y [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), el típo `void` lo es todo y lo es nada, pero, no tengo muy claro de qué vá esto.

¿Alguien me explica qué es `void` y sus funciones en los diversos lenguajes que lo utilizan?

**<sub>Nota: *He utilizado sólo [c](/questions/tagged/c) y [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) porque no estoy seguro de utilizar la etiqueta [lenguaje-agnostico](/questions/tagged/lenguaje-agnostico), sientase libre de editar este fragmento y las etiquetas de la pregunta.*</sub>**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Para [c](/questions/tagged/c) y [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) es cierto que `void` prácticamente significa *nada*, pero agregandole un simple asterisco *(`*`)*, puede ser *todo* o, mejor dicho, **¡Lo que sea!**

Empezando por partes, la palabra reservada `void` tiene los siguientes casos de usos en C *(Entre otros)*:

#### Especificador de tipo:

```
void HacerAlgoQueNoRetorna(void);
```

Arriba está la declaración de una función de tipo `void`, es decir, que no retorna un valor de algún típo y por tanto, no se puede tener una variable de típo `void` a la cual asignarle el *retorno* de la función:

```
void MiVariable; /* Imposible! Se desatarán las aguas si esto pasase. */
```

Y mucho menos:

```
void MiVariable = HacerAlgoQueNoRetorna(); /* ¡RENUNCIO! */
```

Si se ha fijado en el primer bloque de código, he utilizado `(void)` en la *parte* de los parámetros que utiliza el método declarado ahí, esto se explica más abajo.

#### *Sellador* de funciones.

Por defecto, las funciones de C son [variadicas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) cuando `void` no se pone explícitamente entre los parentesis de la definición de las funciones<sup>1</sup>:

```
void HacerAlgo() {}      /* Sí, entre esos paréntesis. */

int main(void) {
  HacerAlgo(10, 15, 20); /* Es totalmente normal, no pasará nada. */
}
```

Sin embargo, cuando utilizamos `void` entre los paréntesis, entonces lo anterior no funciona:

```
void HacerAlgo(void) {}  /* Sí, entre esos paréntesis. */

int main(void) {
  HacerAlgo(10, 15, 20); /* Es totalmente normal, espera... ¡ERROR! */
}
```

#### Suprimir... ¿Advertencias?

Nunca es bueno suprimir las advertencias que arroja tu compilador cuando hay problemas *no contundentes* pero que pueden causar un comportamiento no especificado en tu software:

```
(void)fread(mi_contenido, 1, total, mi_archivo);
```

En este contexto, `(void)` sirve como *operador de casteo* o conversión... como andamos *casteando* a la nada, el valor no sirve de nada *¡Hombre!*

Sin embargo, hay algunos compiladores que en su lugar arrojan una advertencia al utilizar la conversión a `void`.

#### Lo que todos esperabamos... `void *` es lo que sea, o... eso pensabamos.

Sí, `void`, acompañado de un `*`, es un potente tipo de dato que almacena un puntero a cualquier otro tipo de dato ya existente, de hecho, es lo que retorna las funciones que reservan memoria:

```
void *malloc(size_t sz);
void *calloc(size_t *sz, size_t nelem);
void *realloc(void *old, size_t new_size);
```

Y esto es porque `void *` es un puntero a una dirección de memoria cuyo tipo es *desconocido*<sup>2</sup>, que es lo que haces en el código que tienes en la pregunta, defines un *campo* de tipo `void *` y *adivinas* su valor por medio de otra variable.

Realmente creo que `void *` debería ser *evitado* o sólo ser usado cuando el valor al que apunta se sabe a ciencia exacta:

```
void *mi_memoria = calloc(1, 1000); /* Reservamos 1000 bytes. */
```

De hecho, puedo hacer lo que yo quiera con esa memoria<sup>3</sup>:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  void *mi_memoria = calloc(1, 1000);
  int  *como_int = mi_memoria;          /* No hay problema alguno.   */
  int   t = 0;
  int   sz = (1000 / sizeof(int)) - sizeof(int); /* Sepamos el tamaño. */
  while (t <= sz)
    como_int[t] = t * 4;
  t = 0;
  while (t <= sz)
    printf("como_int[%d] = %d\n", t, como_int[t]);
  free(mi_memoria);
  return 0;
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior, lo he utilizado para almacenar un puntero de memoria reservada de forma dinámica de 1000 bytes, pero como no sabía que hacer con esos bytes, así que los utilicé para guardar enteros, de la misma forma, puedo convertir ese puntero a `void` a un puntero a `char` y almacenar una cadena de texto.

Pero, ¿Qué queda cuando pasamos un puntero de cualquier otra cosa a un parámetro de tipo `void *`? Lo importante de esto es que C es algo permisivo *(No quisiera que tuviera hijas)* y automaticamente, realiza la conversión a `void *`<sup>4</sup> para que la función llamada pueda trabajar con el puntero pasado por argumento.

El puntero a `void` es un típo muy potente en sabias manos, sin embargo, puede traer descuidos y problemas en el código, como toda buena práctica de C, es recomendable no abusar de este típo.

---

<sup>1</sup>: [Ideone](https://ideone.com/zH1LgN) para comprobarlo.
<sup>2</sup>: No es del todo desconocido, pero un apuntador de tipo void sólo nos deja saber la dirección a la que apunta, no los datos que contiene.
<sup>3</sup>: [Ideone](https://ideone.com/v718si) para comprobarlo.
<sup>4</sup>: Todos los punteros tienen el mismo tamaño, lo único que cambia es la forma de interpretar las direcciones de memoria según el entorno en el que corre.

Comment: Gran respuesta, +1. Sólo una pequeña duda: todo lo escrito se aplica exactamente para C++ o existen algunas diferencias?

Comment: He puesto que es válido para [tag:C], sin embargo, creo que es totalmente aplicable a [tag:C++]